SFMCSDK for iOS - Framework Signature Validation Failed
We have been facing an issue recently with the SFMCSDK.xcframework signature on Xcode15. The builds are failing due to the signature check in XCode failing. https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-sdk-ios
Specifically, informing us that the certificate of the entity that has signed the framework has been revoked.
Error: The signing certificate has been revoked (CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED)
We have tested the last 3 versions of the framework, but it looks like the entire certificate chain was revoked.
Additionally, we have noticed that the https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS has been archived recently.
Could anyone shed some light on this issue and why was the repository archived?
Thank You.


We are looking into this, We Will keep you posted.
Update
Our SDK certificates was scheduled to expire on 04/21/2024. We renewed our certificate earlier this week due to the recent apple conformance with code signing, we had to update existing releases with the updated code signature. Resigning the affected 8.1.1 and 8.1.2 versions of the SDK was made as opposed to deprecating those builds and forcing an update to an 8.1.3 release.
For cocoapods :
Please remove the pods, clean the cache and do a pod install.
Below is the Command:
rm -rf Pods/MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk/ Pods/MarketingCloudSDK/ && pod cache clean 'MarketingCloudSDK' && pod cache clean 'MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk' && pod install.

For SPM :
If you face any errors in fetching the latest updates, please do
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm 
rm -rf ~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm

Go to Xcode File-> Packages -> Resolve Package Versions, this should update the frameworks.
For Manual inclusion:
Please download the same or latest version of SDKs from the following links which have updated code signatures:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-sdk-ios/releases
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/releases

For context: Prakashini works for Salesforce. Please do update this answer as the situation changes!

Thank you, it seems that the updated and signed framework solved the issue.

Why would you do it this way instead of changing the version number? It makes everything much more difficult for the dev's (by forcing a manual workaround) plus it slows everything else down by forcing me to purge my entire cache.

Appears Salesforce's last few releases were replaced and have new hashes, likely because of this? Xcode doesn't like this and breaks our builds, which is why I found this post.
"Revision ea47dbb124945dc32dc447f3bf1c792fde6a6c74 for marketingcloudsdk-ios remoteSourceControl https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS version 8.1.2 does not match previously recorded value 151b9f0fd0f1ea1be2ad26c93f60c3c6aa40f9cb"
Can you also cut a new release(s) with updated signatures as that'll be easier for most developers to update to, and probably safer than replacing existing releases.

Answering this to close the issue.
After opening the issue the team at salesforce submitted a new release with an updated framework signature.
The commit that contains the updated framework: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/commit/ea47dbb124945dc32dc447f3bf1c792fde6a6c74

Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
